# Split number in parts and grab the closest to a number MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to split a number in parts

Ex:

```
256 / 4 = [64 128 192 256]
```

And grab a given number (eg. 121) and detect which one is the closest, in this case 128.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ride on @fiveclubs answer:

```
 d=4;
 c=256;
 a=arrayfun(@(x)(x*d),(1:d)*c/d^2 ) % ;)
```

will give you the array, then, as he suggested

```
 b=121;
 [~,i] = min(abs(a-b))
 a(i)
```

the clossest point.

Comment: `linspace(c/d,c,d)` might be more elegant to get `a`.

Comment: yes, my actuall suggestion `(1:d)*c/d` is very similar. The arrayfun is just a joke of sorts...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing as written, but I'll answer what I think you are asking:

Given an array `a = [64 128 192 256]` and a number, say `b = 121`, determine which element in `a` is closest to `b`:

```
[~,i] = min(abs(a-b))
a(i)
```

Then `a(i)` will contain the number closest to `b`.

Comment: Nice! But how do I generate the `a` array? I mean, I want to split the number 256 in two parts, then I get [128 256]. Now I want in four parts, the I get [64 128 192 256] ...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to compute all the parts

```
function[res] = splitgrab(n, nParts, x)    % (256, 4, 121)
d = n / nParts;                            % d = 64
mult = max(1, min(nParts, round(x / d)));  % mult = 2
res = mult * d;                            % res = 64 * 2
```

Comment: This `y` comes from where?

Comment: This makes the most sense, it's scalable and efficient.